# How do I correctly punctuate the phrase "that is" in the context of an explanation?

Tags: phrases, punctuation

I find myself wanting to use the phrase "that is" or "that's to say" but often can't figure out what sort of punctuation I use with it. I *think* it's an explanatory phrase, but I'm not sure.

> I mean, it happens all the time, **that is, birds eating and ants crawling about,** but I felt connected to those beings if for just a moment.

Another alternative that doesn't feel right to me at all:

> I mean, it happens all the time. **That is, birds eating and ants crawling about,** but I felt connected to those beings if for just a moment.

Likewise, I think I might be able to justify an em dash, but I'm always nervous about using them for lack of proper understanding.

> I mean, it happens all the time–**that is**, birds eating and ants crawling about–but I felt connected to those beings if for just a moment.

**Can someone provide a good example of how to use that phrase?**

Comment: Your version with the em dashes seems just right, except that all three examples would make a lot more sense without the *not,* so that the final condition would read "if just for a moment" or "if only for a moment."

Comment: @BrianDonovan Thanks for pointing that out! I totally agree that it sounds better without the "not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**That is** or **i.e.** is used for clarifying a statement. Think of it as "in essence" or "in other words".

Use **that is** when you want to  explain what you just said in a different way.A definition, metaphor, or a clarification can follow.

You may want to check examples [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-%22i.e.%22-Versus-%22e.g.%22) (Read the part that explains i.e)

I am including a few examples here:

> 1. The elephant is a pachyderm, i.e., an animal with thick skin and nails resembling hooves.
> 2. I went to my least favorite place (i.e., the dentist).

Answer (score 0):

I would punctuate "that is" as you would "for example" in an extended example. "A writer might punctuate 'that is' in a number of ways; for example, one might set off the phrase that begins 'that is' with em dashes."

I actually came here looking for the answer to the very same question, so I appreciate the responses. Do note that while one can use "i.e." in parentheses, one should NEVER use "i.e.," "e.g.," or "etc." outside of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

“that is” is a phrase that means “for example,” and comes from the Latin, “id est.” It is not the same as “that’s,” nor can it be conjugated like a verb, so it has no past tense. Therefore, to render it as “that was” is incorrect. It is set off by commas, making it an appositive, which isn’t a verb at all, but “a word or group of words placed next to a noun or pronoun in order to identify, rename or explain it. An appositive can be a noun, a pronoun or a phrase or clause acting as a noun.”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).